# GNU coreutils need suggestions

Tags: gnu, coreutils

Can anyone please suggest me some book or website from where I can learn about gnu coreutils to get more knowledge about terminal commands.
An interactive book or website would be a nice start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GNU project has an [official manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html) freely available on their website.

That said, it seems like a Herculean task (and a waste of time to a certain degree) reading it entirely in one go since the number of tools in Coreutils is too vast, and some of them do not see much use except for fairly specialized tasks.

Thus, you will likely be better off look up the topic or the command of your interest as supplementary information for what you've read in the man pages and Internet forums.

Comment: Much of the coreutils utilities are implementations of standard Unix tools. Any Unix tutorial will probably do as long as it keeps to Linux or just basic Unix command line usage.  I'm sure the web is absolutely filled with these (and most will be bad).